# Makefile for Java example request

Tags: java, makefile

I'm looking for a straightforward example of make used with Java (I know ant is better, but our instructor wants us to learn make now for c later, I believe). All of the ones I've seen online all seem different and more complicated than I would need at this stage, so I'm just looking for a simple example.

[directory like so: `~/CSC/SomeAssignment/src` where all the .java files are located; `~/CSC/SomeAssignment/bin` where all the `.class` files are supposed to go.]

I know how to do a Makefile within the src folder (.class files end up in the src folder too), but how do I do it such that the class files end up in bin?

Comment: By passing `-d` to `javac`.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15756399/basics-on-java-makefile?rq=1